# Number of expected state transitions for two heads in a row with a fake coin?

Tags: probability

I am now doing [Number of expected state transitions for two heads in a row?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322482/number-of-expected-state-transitions-for-two-heads-in-a-row) with a fake coin which shows heads with a probability of $p$.

First we can calculate how many steps this takes, using the same logic as we did with the normal coin:

$$(1-p)(s+1)+p(1-p)(s+2)+2p^2 = s$$

to find we need $\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{p}$ steps.

We have the following states:

- A: the start: the previous flip was a tail.
- B: the previous flip was the first head
- C: the end. two heads have been flipped.

Then we can calculate the expected number of state transitions:

$$\begin{align}E(A \to A)&=x\\E(A \to B) &= y\\E(B \to A) &= z\\E(B \to C) &= 1. \end{align}$$

We know the sum of them and we can apply definitions: $$\begin{align}x+y+z+1&=\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{p}\\p&=\frac{y}{x+y}\\p&=\frac1{z+1}\end{align}$$

Solving this is very easy, we get $$\begin{align}x&=\frac1{p^2}-\frac1p\\y&=\frac1p\\z&=\frac1p-1\end{align}$$.

How curious. The question is this: could we prove $$y=z+1$$ independently of this calculation? It's surprising me because it doesn't depend on $p$ at all. If we could prove this then we would not need to calculate the number of steps first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes.

What can happen after a head follows a tail? Either we get another head which ends the party or we flip another tail which means we are back at state A.

So instead of calculating the number of steps first we could solve $$\begin{align}p&=\frac{y}{x+y}\\p&=\frac1{z+1}\\y&=z+1\end{align}$$ which is so much simpler.